# What does either of the appreviations b and u refer to

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

In
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example

there is an example as shown below in the code section. I would like to know what is

```
b
u 
and b.u?
```

Code:

```
[timeout:600];
rel[admin_level=2][wikidata]->.a;
foreach .a -> .b (
  rel.a(if:t[wikidata] == b.u(t[wikidata]))->.d;
  rel.d(if: id() == d.min(id()) && d.count(relations) > 1 );
  convert rel ::id = _.u(id()),
             wikidata = _.u(t[wikidata]),
             all_relation_ids = d.set( id() );
  (._ ; .result; ) -> .result;
);

.result out;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are just arbitrary names for *[sets](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Sets)*. Sets contain OSM elements such as nodes, ways and relations. If you don't specify an explicit set name then the default set named `_` will be used.

From your example: Set `a` is populated by this line:

```
rel[admin_level=2][wikidata]->.a;
```

Then it will loop through set `a` and populate set `b`:

```
foreach .a -> .b (
```

Inside the loop, a set `d` gets created:

```
rel.a(if:t[wikidata] == b.u(t[wikidata]))->.d;
```

Comment: what is u then please

Comment: `u` is an [*aggregator* function](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Union_and_Set) for sets.

In my opinion, Overpass QL has a rather poor naming scheme. At least for some operations.